# Using IN operator in DAX with Power Bi Desktop chart?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm new to DAX so please bear with me.

Can I use the IN operator in DAX to create a query directly in Power Bi desktop?

For example, the screenshot below displays over 120 curencies in `DimCurrency.CurrencyName`. Is it possible to create a DAX query where I can include all my filters using `IN` operator?

For example, maybe something like this?

```
CALCULATE (
    [Sales Amount],
    Products[Color] IN { "Red", "Black" }
)
```

[image]

The reason I'm interested in using DAX is because my current filter has over 200 different items, so I don't want to scroll through the 200-item list and select 5 different items.

Comment: Why do you need DAX instead of just setting a filter in the fIlter pane or using a slicer visual?

Comment: In this example, `DimCurrency.CurrencyName` has 200 different currencies and my filter will include 50 currencies. I don't want to scroll through the 200 filters and select each of the 50 curerncies.

Answer (score 0):

This is a data modeling problem. In Dimensional Modeling terms your Dimension needs some additional attribute hierarchies to drive the filtering.  This is just like why a Calendar table doen't just have a Day column, it needs Month, Year, Quarter, so you don't have to select all the individual Days.

Basically DimCurrency needs an additional column, so that you can include those 50 currencies by selecting fewer values of that new column.

One way to modify your data model is with [DAX calculated columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-tutorial-create-calculated-columns), with an expression of the form

```
IsFacoriteCurrency = 'DimCurrency'[CurrencyName] in {"Algerian Dinar","Argentine Peso"}
```

you can also modify the data model in the data source or in Power Query.

Comment: They can't be predermined filters because they are entirely dependent on the end-users.

Comment: Today the user may want to filter by the worst 30 currencies and tomorrow he may want to see the trending pattern of the US Dollar, Euro, Rupee, and 10 other currencies he needs to monitor.

Comment: Then find an appropriate slicer.  There are many both built-in and in the marketplace.

Comment: Thanks, but can I add a _New Column_ when the data source is an SSAS cube?

Comment: Since I'm new to Power BI, can you recommend a slicer that may do something like this? I'm not sure how I'd search for a slicer with this type of filtering.

Comment: Give Q&A a try maybe?